# multilevel stan model with three hierarchies

Tags: bayesian, multi-level, stan

Assume I have a multilevel structure of data. With a global distribution, from which I draw a highlevel distribution from which i draw a lowlevel distribution from which I draw my response variable. How would I implement such a thing in a stan model.

Below is a minimal example which I hope illustrates the problem. In the stan code there is

- one commented "model" section which is working, but ignores the mutlilevel aspect and treats every lower level equal, irrespective of the highlevel origin and provides therefor not shrinkage by the highlevel order (see pic).
- A "model"section with a forloop, which I though would do what I want, but takes forever to finish, and with a lot of warnings (Rhat, treedepth, Bayesion Fraction, low ESS)

I am quite inexperienced with modeling and all tutorials on ML-Modeling do not have the Loop-Approach I though would make sense here, so I suspect I am completely heading in the wrong direction with that. So any help will be highly appreciated.

**R-Code to generate and run the model**

````
```{r}
library(ggplot2)
library(rstan)
library(bayesplot)
library(loo)


set.seed(0)
numberOFTest <- 50
resposeList <- c()
highLevelIndexList <- c()
lowLevelIndexList  <- c()
for (highLevelIndex in seq(3)) {
  highLevelMu <- rnorm(1,0,5) #High Level avarage drawn drom normal dist
  for (lowLevelIndex in seq(6)) {
    lowLevelMu <- rnorm(1,highLevelMu,3) #low Level avarage drawn drom normal dist
    resposeList <- c(resposeList, rnorm(numberOFTest,lowLevelMu,1))
    highLevelIndexList <- c(highLevelIndexList, rep(highLevelIndex,numberOFTest) )
    lowLevelIndexList <- c(lowLevelIndexList, rep(paste0(highLevelIndex,lowLevelIndex),numberOFTest) )
  
  }
}
lowLevelIndexList <- as.integer( as.factor(lowLevelIndexList))

dat <- list(Nr=length(resposeList),
            Nh=length(unique(highLevelIndexList)),
            Nl=length(unique(lowLevelIndexList)),
            #############
              r=seq(length(resposeList)),
              response=resposeList,
              highLevelIndex=(highLevelIndexList),
              lowLevelIndex=(lowLevelIndexList)
              )


model <- stan(data=dat, file="modle.stan",chains = 4, cores = 8, control=list(adapt_delta=0.95),iter = 2000)
````

**The stan code**

```
data {
  int<lower=1> Nr; // number of rows (entries)
  int<lower=1> Nh; // number of highlevels 
  int<lower=1> Nl; // number of low levels 
  int<lower=1> r[Nr]; // rownumber
  real response[Nr]; // 
  int<lower=1> highLevelIndex[Nr]; // 
  int<lower=1> lowLevelIndex[Nr]; // 
}


parameters {
  real<lower=0> sigma; //
  real<lower=0> sigma_global; //
  real<lower=0> sigma_hL; //
  real<lower=0> sigma_lL; //
  real a_global; //
  real a_hL[Nh]; //
  real a_lL[Nl]; //
}

transformed parameters {
  vector[Nr] mu; 
  for (rowIndex in 1:Nr) { //
    mu[rowIndex] = a_lL[lowLevelIndex[rowIndex]];
  }
}


//Idea of what I want

model {
  sigma_global ~ exponential(0.1);  //hyper
  sigma_hL ~ exponential(0.1);  //hyper
  sigma_lL ~ exponential(0.1);  //hyper
  a_global ~ normal(0,sigma_global);
  //-----------
  for (rowIndex in 1:Nr) { //
    a_hL[highLevelIndex[rowIndex]] ~   normal(a_global, sigma_hL);  //hyper
    a_lL[lowLevelIndex[rowIndex]] ~   normal(a_hL[highLevelIndex[rowIndex]], sigma_lL);  
  }
    ////
  sigma ~ exponential(0.1);  
  response ~ normal(mu, sigma);
}


/*
model {///// Working but not what I want
  a_lL ~   normal(0, 10); 
  ////
  sigma ~ exponential(0.1);  
  response ~ normal(mu, sigma);
}
*/

generated quantities { // for the PPC and loo
  real n_rep[Nr];
  vector[Nr] log_lik;
  
  for (i in 1:Nr){
    n_rep[i] = normal_rng(mu[i], sigma);
    log_lik[i] = normal_lpdf(response[i] | mu[i], sigma);
  }
```

}

**mcmc_areas of the working modle with no shrinkage within each block (1-6),(7-12) and (12-18)**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the mistake: I needed to map the lowlevel values to the highlevel ones, with a look up table. Below is now a working version, which also just takes a second to finish.

```
data {
  int<lower=1> Nr; // number of rows (entries)
  int<lower=1> Nh; // number of highlevels 
  int<lower=1> Nl; // number of low levels 
  real response[Nr]; // 
  int<lower=1> highLevelIndex[Nr]; // 
  int<lower=1> lowLevelIndex[Nr]; // 
  int<lower=1> lookUp[Nl];//lookuptable which highlevel value a lowlevel value fits to
}

parameters {
  real<lower=0> sigma; //
  real<lower=0> sigma_hL; //
  real<lower=0> sigma_lL; //
  real a_hL[Nh]; //
  real a_lL[Nl]; //
}

transformed parameters {
  vector[Nr] mu; 
  for (rowIndex in 1:Nr) { //
    mu[rowIndex] = a_lL[lowLevelIndex[rowIndex]];
  }
}

model {
  sigma_hL ~ exponential(0.01);
  a_hL ~          normal(0, sigma_hL); 
  sigma_lL ~ exponential(0.01);
  for (lLIdx in 1:Nl) { //
    a_lL[lLIdx] ~  normal(a_hL[lookUp[lLIdx]],sigma_lL);  
  }
  ////
  sigma ~ exponential(0.1);  
  response ~ normal(mu, sigma);
}

generated quantities { // for the PPC and loo
  real n_rep[Nr];
  vector[Nr] log_lik;
  
  for (i in 1:Nr){
    n_rep[i] = normal_rng(mu[i], sigma);
    log_lik[i] = normal_lpdf(response[i] | mu[i], sigma);
  }
}
```